# How to create a header.php and footer.php with CSS files?

Tags: php, html, css, header, footer

I am building my site using HTML files. I would like my header and footer to be dynamic so that I can easily update anything... verses updating 10+ files every time. I'm not familiar with creating a .php file for this use.

I've researched and tried a few ways to do this... but it's not working...I know I'm doing this wrong. haha...

I do not want to make my index.html into index.php. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Here's some info: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html, but I'd consider using a layout file (if you haven't already). There are other ways to do this as well.

Comment: server-side includes are an option (nothing to do with PHP), otherwise you have to make it `index.php`

Comment: You could change your server setup to serve html as php if you really want to, but the better approach is to change all URLs to use extension-less names. The basic idea is each page is a directory with an index file. You point people to the directory and the corresponding index file runs. No user ever sees the file extensions.

Comment: Google is your friend, there are LOTS of examples on how to build a php template. Here's just one: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-create-php-website-template/

Comment: OK wow, you're getting a lot of bad answers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely can't make your index a php file. Then, you can always make an ajax request to get the header and footer. However, it is very simple to have a dynamic header and footer with php.

The index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <body>
       <?php include 'header.html'; ?>
       <?php include 'footer.html'; ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

The header.html file

```
<header>
    <p>Some stuff in my header...</p>
</header>
```

The footer.html file

```
<footer>
    <p>Some stuff in your footer</p>
</footer>
```

The style.css file

```
header {
    /* My styles here */
}

footer {
    /* My styles here */
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to load the header and footer. Create a header.html and footer.html and load them via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<!--#include virtual="head.html" --> 
<h1>Body goes here...</h1>
<!--#include virtual="footer.html" --> 
</body>
</html>
```

you could try something like this.

If it doesn't seem to work, try changing your extension to .shtml, instead of .html.

for more info on server include you can try this site: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/include.html

Comment: this is a server-side include and requires the `shtml` extension or a specially configured server

Comment: yeas but is a solution using only html.

Comment: No it isn't. It uses HTML and *Apache*

Comment: (to be clear, by the time the page content is treated as HTML rather than just text, the include has already been done. Those lines are text substitution. Nothing to do with HTML at all. They just look like HTML)

Comment: still html, with a minor server config, php is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Server Side Includes and save your files as .shtml
More information from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes

The syntax is eg. `<!--#include file="header.shtml" -->`

Answer (score 0):

Edit your .htaccess file and add these line, this will tell apache to treat .html as .php

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

and for .htm

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

Comment: Bad idea. This will slow down serving all static content and can mess up caching.